# changing a php variable name throughout for loop

Tags: php

I have an array that I want to rename so that the values are stored depending on what number the for loop is on.  I tried something like this but its giving me an error.

```
for ($i =0;$i<4;$i++){

$array.$i = array();

push stuff into array;




}
```

So at the next iteration the array is called array1, then array2 and so forth.  What is the best way to do this.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that you want to create four different arrays, with names from $array1 to $array4 ?

Comment: use a multidimensional array. $array[$i] ...

Comment: correct.  I have different leagues, with different teams.  So I want to create an array for each team of each league if that makes any sense.

Comment: @user541597: it does. So use nested arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To literally answer your question:

```
$arrayName = 'array' . $i;
$$arrayName = array();
$$arrayName[] = ...
```

What you *really* want is a multidimensional array though:

```
$array[$i] = array();
$array[$i][] = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), in which the double dollar sign indicates that the name of the variable is taken from a variable.

```
$varname = "array";
for ($i =0;$i<4;$i++){
    $newvarname = $varname . $i
    $$newvarname = new array()
    push stuff into array;
}
```

I would add that in these cases, a simpler solution is often to use an array in which the desired variable names are indices. So instead of creating `$array1`, `$array2`, and so forth, you'd have:

```
$arrays = array (
    'array1' => array(stuff),
    'array2' => array(stuff),
    'array3' => array(stuff),
    'array4' => array(stuff)
}
```

At least, I find it easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the array using the $$ notation for variable variables (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

So, something like this should work (untested):

```
for ($i =0;$i<4;$i++){

  $thisArrayName = 'array'.$i;
  $$thisArrayName = array();

  push stuff into array;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need array of array

```
for ($i =0;$i<4;$i++){

   $array[$i] = array();

    push stuff into array;
}
```